# How can I disable firebase reCAPTCHA in react native expo app?

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I am Using Firebase phone-auth for User Login and  doing this (Code Below), but I don't want user to verify through reCaptcha.So How can I disable google firebase authentication ReCaptcha in the react native - Expo Project? I referred to so many resources I haven't found any solution.

firebaseConfig has been defined then:

```
export default function spLogin({ navigation }) {
  const ....  //multiple useStates 
  return (
    <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={Keyboard.dismiss} accessible={false}>
      <View style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%", backgroundColor: "#fff" }}>
        
        <FirebaseRecaptchaVerifierModal
          ref={recaptchaVerifier}
          firebaseConfig={firebaseConfig}
          attemptInvisibleVerification={attemptInvisibleVerification}
        />

        <Text style={{ marginTop: 20, marginLeft: "10%" }}>
          Enter phone number
        </Text>
        <PhoneInput
          ref={phoneInput}
          defaultValue={value}
          defaultCode="IN"
          layout="first"
          onChangeText={(text) => {
            setValue(text);
          }}
          onChangeFormattedText={(text) => {
            setPhoneNumber(text);
          }}
          withDarkTheme
          withShadow
          autoFocus
        />
        <Button
          title="Send Verification Code"
          disabled={!phoneNumber}
          onPress={async () => {
            try {
              const phoneProvider = new firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider();
              const verificationId = await phoneProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(
                phoneNumber,
                recaptchaVerifier.current
              );
              setVerificationId(verificationId);
              showMessage({
                text: "Verification code has been sent to your phone.",
              });
            } catch (err) {
              showMessage({ text: `Error: ${err.message}`, color: "red" });
            }
          }}
        />
        <Text style={{ marginLeft: "10%", marginTop: 20 }}>
          Enter Verification code
        </Text>
        <TextInput
          keyboardType="numeric"
          style={{ marginVertical: 10, marginLeft: "10%", fontSize: 17 }}
          editable={!!verificationId}
          placeholder="123456"
          onChangeText={setVerificationCode}
        />
        <Button
          title="Confirm Verification Code"
          disabled={!verificationId}
          onPress={async () => {
            try {
              const credential = firebase.auth.PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                verificationId,
                verificationCode
              );
              await firebase
                .auth()
                .signInWithCredential(credential)
                .then(() => {
                      navigation.navigate("x1");
                  });
                });
            } catch (err) {
              showMessage({ text: `Error: ${err.message}`, color: "red" });
            }
          }}
        />
        {message ? (
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={[
              StyleSheet.absoluteFill,
              { backgroundColor: 0xffffffee, justifyContent: "center" },
            ]}
            onPress={() => showMessage(undefined)}
          >
            <Text
              style={{
                color: message.color || "blue",
                fontSize: 17,
                textAlign: "center",
                margin: 20,
              }}
            >
              {message.text}
            </Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        ) : (
          undefined
        )}
        {attemptInvisibleVerification && <FirebaseRecaptchaBanner />}
      </View>
    </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
  );
}
```

Comment: This has come up regularly before, so check the questions I linked and more from https://www.google.com/search?q=How+can+I+disable+firebase+reCAPTCHA+in+react+native+expo+app%3F

Comment: Hey @FrankvanPuffelen not able to get the result by those solution that is why I asked. Request you to tell me where should I make the necessary changes in my code to get the desired result.